# Metal off-screen drawing with Multi-Sampling

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, metal

How do I render primitives into off screen texture, not directly into the screen?

I have a set of triangles and corresponding color, I just want to draw them the same way I do to screen, but into off screen texture, that I can save into a file.

Can anybody show me a code sample of that?

Comment: What have you tried? In Metal, all rendering is done to a texture; the only difference is whether you're drawing to a texture wrapped in a drawable that is then presented to the screen, or a texture you manage for yourself. If you want to draw to the latter, just create an `MTLTexture` of the appropriate size and format and set it as the texture of the first color attachment of your render pass descriptor. Then, you can use the `getBytes` API to get the image data and write it out.

Comment: look at my code, I've updated the question

Comment: I guess my problem is that my coordinates are wrong, maybe I should set viewport or maybe custom projection...

Comment: Right, you should be returning clip space coordinates from your vertex shader. If your vertices aren't already specified in that space, you will need to use some kind of projection matrix to move them into it.

Comment: How can I do that? My coordinates are in pixels now, I have no idea how to convert them to be appropriate.. now I see only a part of an image with HUGE triangles...

Comment: If your vertices are in pixel-based coordinates, an orthographic projection matrix that scales and biases them such that x and y always fall between -1 and 1 should work. See `makeOrthographicMatrix` in [this article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/90592/liquidfun-tutorial-2).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I realized it myself. This code does the job, with only exception that it draw too huge triangles, but that is a different topic for Vertex function.

Here is my code:

```
    let fragmentProgram = defaultLibrary.newFunctionWithName("image_fragmentT")
    let vertexProgram = defaultLibrary.newFunctionWithName("image_vertexT")


    struct VertexT {
        var x, y, z, w : Float
        var r, g, b, a : Float
    }

    let vertexDescriptor = MTLVertexDescriptor()
    vertexDescriptor.attributes[0].offset = 0
    vertexDescriptor.attributes[0].format = .Float4
    vertexDescriptor.attributes[0].bufferIndex = 0

    vertexDescriptor.attributes[1].offset = 0
    vertexDescriptor.attributes[1].format = .Float4
    vertexDescriptor.attributes[1].bufferIndex = 0

    vertexDescriptor.layouts[0].stepFunction = .PerVertex
    vertexDescriptor.layouts[0].stride = sizeof(VertexT)

    let pipelineStateDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
    pipelineStateDescriptor.vertexDescriptor = vertexDescriptor
    pipelineStateDescriptor.vertexFunction = vertexProgram
    pipelineStateDescriptor.fragmentFunction = fragmentProgram
    pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .RGBA8Unorm;
    pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].blendingEnabled = true
    pipelineStateDescriptor.sampleCount = 4
    pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].rgbBlendOperation =    MTLBlendOperation.Add
    pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].alphaBlendOperation = MTLBlendOperation.Add
    pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceRGBBlendFactor = MTLBlendFactor.SourceAlpha
    pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceAlphaBlendFactor = MTLBlendFactor.SourceAlpha
    pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor = MTLBlendFactor.OneMinusSourceAlpha
    pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationAlphaBlendFactor = MTLBlendFactor.OneMinusSourceAlpha


    let sampleDesc = MTLTextureDescriptor()
    sampleDesc.textureType = MTLTextureType.Type2DMultisample
    sampleDesc.width = inTexture.width
    sampleDesc.height = inTexture.height
    sampleDesc.sampleCount = 4
    sampleDesc.pixelFormat = .RGBA8Unorm
    sampleDesc.storageMode = .Private
    sampleDesc.usage = .RenderTarget

    let sampletex = device.device.newTextureWithDescriptor(sampleDesc)
    let renderPassDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()

    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = sampletex
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].resolveTexture = outTexture
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .Clear
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0)
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = .MultisampleResolve

    let renderCB = commandQueue.commandBuffer()

    let renderCommandEncoder = renderCB.renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor(renderPassDescriptor)
    let pipelineState = try! device.device.newRenderPipelineStateWithDescriptor(pipelineStateDescriptor)
    renderCommandEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState)

    let vertexBuf = device.device.newBufferWithLength(triangles.count * 3 * sizeof(VertexT), options: .CPUCacheModeDefaultCache)

    var vBufPointer = [VertexT]()

    for i in 0..<triangles.count {

        // create buffer here
    }

    memcpy(vertexBuf.contents(), &vBufPointer, triangles.count * 3 * sizeof(VertexT))

    renderCommandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuf, offset: 0, atIndex: 0)
    renderCommandEncoder.drawPrimitives(.Triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: triangles.count * 3)
    renderCommandEncoder.endEncoding()
    renderCB.commit()
    renderCB.waitUntilCompleted()
```

You image now is in `outTexture` variable.

Comment: I coincidentally have this same problem today, but still having weird issues. I think the resolution to my own issue is to use .MultisampleResolve, but what are the settings for outTexture's descriptor?